# Getting the imageDenoising CUDA example to work using a MATLAB CUDAKernel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cuda, filtering, gpgpu

#### TL;DR

I'm looking for a way to extract a part of an existing CUDA Toolkit example and turn it into a [CUDAKernel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/cudakernel_object.html) executable in MATLAB.

#### The Story

In an attempt to obtain a short-runtime implementation of the non-local means (NLM) 2D filter, I stumbled upon the [imageDenoising example provided with the CUDA Toolkit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#image-denoising) which implements two variants of this filter, called NLM & NLM2 (or "quick NLM").

Having no previous experience with CUDA coding, I initially attempted to follow [MATLAB's documentation on the subject](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html), which resulted in several strange errors including: [ptx compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25024720/3372061), [multiple entry points](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59691-using-a-templated-cuda-kernel-via-matlab) and [wrong number of inputs in the C prototype](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7744-executing-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-the-gpu). At this point I realized that this isn't going to be a "just works" case and that some tinkering is required.

So I decided to eliminate the multiple entry point issue by simply deleting parts of `imageDenoising.cu` file and consolidating the relevant `.cuh` (either `..._nlm_kernel.cuh` or `..._nlm2_kernel.cuh`) into the `.cu` so as to obtain a single entry point at any given time. 
To my surprise this actually managed to compile and I was finally able to create a `CUDAKernel` without an error (using the command `k = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('imageDenoising.ptx', 'uint8_T *, int, int, float, float');`).

This however was not enough, because I mistakenly concluded that the 1st argument is the unprocessed image in the form of an RGB matrix (i.e. X*Y*3 `uint8`), and so the result I was getting back was exactly the input but with `0` in the 1st 4 elements.

After searching a bit more I realized that there are additional, and critical, aspects I'm entirely unaware of (like [the need to initialize `__device__` variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16704063/3372061)) to such a conversion process, at which stage I decided to ask for help.

#### The Problem

I'm currently wondering how to efficiently continue from here. While I'd love to hear if this kind of approach can generally bear fruit (and whether a complete example of this process is available somewhere), which other pitfalls I should look out for, and what alternative courses of action I can take (considering my *very* limited knowledge in CUDA and the fact I won't hire anybody else to do this for me), I keep in mind that this is SO and so I must have a **specific programming problem**, so here goes:

> How do I modify `imageDenoising.cu` such that the MATLAB `CUDAKernel` constructed from it will also accept the unprocessed image as an input?

Note: in my application, the input matrix is a 2d, grayscale, `double` matrix.

**Related:** [How CudaMalloc work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938165/how-cudamalloc-work)

P.S.

A working piece of code would obviously be welcomed, but I'd really rather "learn to fish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking an alternative approach to CUDAKernel, using `.MEX`, by doing the following:

1. Setting up the external libraries [OpenCV v2.4.10](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) (**not v3!**) and [mexopencv](http://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/).
2. Writing a small wrapper function for [OpenCV's fastNlMeansDenoising](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html#fastnlmeansdenoising) using the [guidelines of mexopencv for unimplemented functions](http://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/html/), as seen below (excluding the documentation):

```
#include "mexopencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // Check arguments
    if (nlhs != 1 || nrhs<1 || ((nrhs % 2) != 1) )
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("fastNLM:invalidArgs", "Wrong number of arguments");

    // Argument vector  
    vector<MxArray> rhs(prhs, prhs + nrhs);

    // Option processing
      // Defaults:
    double h = 3;
    int templateWindowSize = 7;
    int searchWindowSize = 21;
      // Parsing input name-value pairs:
    for (int i = 1; i<nrhs; i += 2) {
        string key = rhs[i].toString();
        if (key == "h")
            h = rhs[i + 1].toDouble();
        else if (key == "templateWindowSize")
            templateWindowSize = rhs[i + 1].toInt();
        else if (key == "searchWindowSize")
            searchWindowSize = rhs[i + 1].toInt();
        else
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mexopencv:error", "Unrecognized option");
    }

    // Process
    Mat src(rhs[0].toMat()), dst;
    fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst, h, templateWindowSize, searchWindowSize);

    // Convert cv::Mat back to mxArray*
    plhs[0] = MxArray(dst);
}
```

3. Compiling it..... and viola - a working CUDA-accelerated NLM filter.

The answer to my question itself can be found by comparing [`opencv\sources\modules\photo\src\cuda\nlm.cu`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/photo/src/cuda/nlm.cu) (this is the opencv2 path) with [`imageDenoising_nlm2_kernel.cuh`](https://github.com/ndd314/cuda_examples/blob/master/3_Imaging/imageDenoising/imageDenoising_nlm2_kernel.cuh).

This solution worked well for me because it was more important for me to get an NLM filter running, rather than using CUDAKernel.

The main lesson I learned from this (and I'd like to pass on to others) is:

> **Running CUDA code in MATLAB can also be done in ways other than CUDAKernel, such as using `.mex` wrappers as shown above.**